# Using @HTML.labelFor helper in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am creating a view for a model in ASP.NET MVC. I am using `@HTML.LabelFor`

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

but I am getting this error:

> Error CS0411
> The type arguments for method 'LabelExtensions.LabelFor<TModel, TValue>(HtmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Cannot reproduce from my side. But I think you can try to rebuild the project.

Comment: import model with using statement in cshtml file

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange error, but doing what it asks to do can help. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly:

```cs
@Html.LabelFor<YourModelType, TypeOfNameProperty>(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

*Note*: my experience (that knows lots of errors like this) tells me that this error will vanish after some time. During this time, you may use the code above. It's not more than a workaround.